# Python - Recorrer un dataframe y reemplazar valores en filas de manera vectorizada

Tags: python, bucles, dataframe, optimización, comparaciones

Tengo un dataframe la siguiente forma:

|  | TEAM_ID | SEASON_ID | STANDINGSDATE | CONFERENCE | TEAM | G | W | L | W_PCT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1610612762 | 22020 | 2021-03-21 | West | Utah | 41 | 30 | 11 | 0.732 |
| 1 | 1610612762 | 22020 | 2021-03-20 | West | Utah | 41 | 30 | 11 | 0.732 |
| 2 | 1610612762 | 22020 | 2021-03-19 | West | Utah | 41 | 30 | 11 | 0.732 |

Como pueden ver, las filas son iguales a excepción del `STANDINGSDATE`(fecha). Lo que busco es recorrer el dataframe de la manera más óptima posible (el dataframe es grande), a fin de ir comparando de a dos filas consecutivas, y si todos los valores son exactamente iguales, a excepción de la `STANDINGSDATE` (fecha), se concluye que el registro es el mismo y la fila estaría repetida. Consecuentemente se asigna el valor de la fecha más reciente, para luego poder borrar los datos duplicados con `drop_duplicates`.

El dataframe debería quedar de la siguiente manera.

|  | TEAM_ID | SEASON_ID | STANDINGSDATE | CONFERENCE | TEAM | G | W | L | W_PCT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1610612762 | 22020 | 2021-03-21 | West | Utah | 41 | 30 | 11 | 0.732 |
| 1 | 1610612762 | 22020 | 2021-03-21 | West | Utah | 41 | 30 | 11 | 0.732 |
| 2 | 1610612762 | 22020 | 2021-03-21 | West | Utah | 41 | 30 | 11 | 0.732 |

Mi código hasta el momento (Me estoy demorando en todo el dataframe: 4min 39s):

```py
n = df.shape[0]
# sólo se comparan tres columnas
for i, j in zip(range(0, n), range(1, n+1)):
    if df.iloc[i:i+1,1:2].values == df.iloc[j:j+1,1:2].values and\
    df.iloc[i:i+1,4:5].values == df.iloc[j:j+1,4:5].values and\
    df.iloc[i:i+1,5:6].values == df.iloc[j:j+1,5:6].values:
        df.iloc[j:j+1,2:3] = df.iloc[i:i+1,2:3]
```

La idea es evitar `iteritems` y `iterrows`, y opciones en esa misma línea, buscando que sea lo más vectorizado posible.

¡Agradecido de antemano!

Comment: Podrías crearte un dataframe secundario, copia del primero pero dropeando el campo `STANDINGSDATE` y entonces eliminar duplicados ahí con drop_duplicates. Luego seguramente puedas añadir el campo `STANDINGSDATE` pero solo con la max fecha por cada team_id

Comment: lo que quieres es comparar los datos excluyendo el campo `STANDINGSDATE`?

Comment: `@Christian`, efectivamente los comparo excluyendo el campo `STANDINGSDATE`. Si la comparación es correcta (que significa que son iguales, pero registrados en dos días distintos), entonces el valor de `STANDINGSDATE` más actualizado se copia en el o los registros mas antiguos. De esa forma genero registros exactamente iguales, y ya podría eliminar los duplicados. Esa es la lógica con que lo vi, pero puede ser una distinta, como la que propone `@Esei`.

Comment: @c_bass-player Lo siento no puede resolver tu problema :(

Comment: @Christian no hay problema, ya veremos si alguien se le ocurre algo mejor!!

Comment: @c_bass-player Ya encontré la solución

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me di cuenta que existe una función de `pandas` para encontrar los datos duplicados, con `df[columns].duplicated()`, pero como dices que debe omitir `STANDINGSDATE`, pues le pasamos un argumento para que omita ese campo en este caso es así `df.duplicated(df.columns[~df.columns.isin(["STANDINGSDATE"])])`
Donde se le dice que si existe el campo `STANDINGSDATE` no lo tome en cuenta, eso se hace negando la expresion con `~` que, en codigo Pythhon normal es el operador `Bitwise not` pero estos operadores cambian de función dependiendo de donde se utilice, pandas no acepta los operadores normales `and`, `or`, `not`, por lo que se usa su equivalente `&`, `|`, `~`.

Bueno ahora si vamos con el codigo.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('archivo.csv')

#lo convertimos a un DF para mejor manejo
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df = df.duplicated(df.columns[~df.columns.isin(["STANDINGSDATE"])])
print(df)
```

**Salida**

```
2    False
1     True
0    False
dtype: bool
```

Esto nos devuelve valores *boleanos* indicando que valores están repetidos y que valores no lo están. Bueno y ahora que hacemos con eso?, sencillo, utilizamos la función `drop_duplicates()` que eliminara los registros duplicados, y nos quedaremos solo con 1. Esto acepta el mismo parámetro para indicarle que campo no tomar en cuenta

```py
...
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

#reemplazamos el duplicated por:
df = df.drop_duplicates(df.columns[~df.columns.isin(["STANDINGSDATE"])])
print(df)
```

**Salida**

```
      TEAM_ID  SEASON_ID STANDINGSDATE CONFERENCE  TEAM   G   W   L  W_PCT
0  1610612762      22020    2021-03-21       West  Utah  41  30  11  0.732
```

Bueno esto seria casi todo, solo nos falta quedarnos con el registro mas actualizado, ¿Cómo lo hacemos?, pues `drop_duplicates` acepta otro parámetro llamado `keep` el cual sirve para indicar si nos quedaremos con el primero o ultimo elemento que este duplicado, por defecto se queda con el primero, entonces lo que se me ocurrió fue, primero ordenar el *DataFrame* de acuerdo a su campo `STANDINGSDATE` (de mayor a menor), así al eliminar nos quedaremos con el primer registro, que por consecuente será el mas reciente, quedando el codigo asi:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('archivo.csv')
#convertimos a DF
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

#ordenamos de mayor a menor
df = df.sort_values("STANDINGSDATE",ascending=False) 
#print(df)

#eliminamos los registros duplicados y nos quedamos con el mas reciente
df = df.drop_duplicates(df.columns[~df.columns.isin(["STANDINGSDATE"])])
print(df)
```

**Resultado**

```py
      TEAM_ID  SEASON_ID STANDINGSDATE CONFERENCE  TEAM   G   W   L  W_PCT
0  1610612762      22020    2021-03-21       West  Utah  41  30  11  0.732
```

La salida será la misma así cambies el orden de los datos en el `.csv`, vamos ha hacer la prueba con mas datos.

**Datos**

```
TEAM_ID,SEASON_ID,STANDINGSDATE,CONFERENCE,TEAM,G,W,L,W_PCT
1610612762,22021,2021-03-10,West,Utah,41,30,11,0.732
1610612762,22022,2021-03-20,West,Utah,41,30,11,0.732
1610612762,22020,2021-03-19,West,Utah,41,30,11,0.732
1610612762,22021,2021-03-14,West,Utah,41,30,11,0.732
1610612762,22022,2021-03-22,West,Utah,41,30,11,0.732
1610612762,22020,2021-03-10,West,Utah,41,30,11,0.732
```

**Salida**

```
      TEAM_ID  SEASON_ID STANDINGSDATE CONFERENCE  TEAM   G   W   L  W_PCT
4  1610612762      22022    2021-03-22       West  Utah  41  30  11  0.732
2  1610612762      22020    2021-03-19       West  Utah  41  30  11  0.732
3  1610612762      22021    2021-03-14       West  Utah  41  30  11  0.732
```

Funciona!, esta es mi ultima publicación por el día de hoy, espero te sirva, si tienes una duda avísame, buenas noches.

Comment: Solucionaste mi problema y más @Christian. Mi código basura se demoraba 4 min y 47 s y el tuyo pasó a demorarse 91.9 ms (OMG!!). La data total erán 191.112 datos y con reducción de duplicados quedó en 46.200. Aquí mi código había llegado a 46.259, entonces en esos 59 registros que tenemos de diferencia yo me había equivocado, porque la condición de igualdad de registros no la definí con todas las columnas de cada registro, cosa que tu código si hace. Gracias por tu ayuda (aplausos!), aún estoy desarrollando mi código, así que puede que algo más deje por aquí!.

Comment: @c_bass-player de nada, tu problema no me dejaba dormir, sentía que era algo tan fácil que debía tener una solución, en mis intentos estaba logrando algo pero sin resultados exitosos, espero con ansias ver cual será tu próxima pregunta :)