# Problema al convertir un string en float en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, float, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo un problema al leer un archivo de datos desde Python. A continuación escribo el código:

```
data = pd.read_excel("OneDrive/Documentos/Proyecto Municipalidad-Python/MAYO2021.xlsx")
data.head()
```

Imprime el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, Python me toma el decimal en un lugar incorrecto. En mi archivo de Excel se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe cómo podría solucionar para que Python lea los valores correctamente?

Gracias!

Comment: En cuales valores te sale mal los decimales? La notación científica en la tabla de arriba se corresponde con los valores de abajo

Comment: No entiendo dónde ves que se convierte de string a float. En una hoja de excel todos los números son float. Otra cosa es el formato que use la celda para representarlo.

Comment: Si estas usando pandas debes de especificar el tipo de dato con que el lees o escribes el Excel ya que pandas se puede confundir

Comment: Puedes mirara esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/460399/183782)

Comment: ¿Habían comentarios entre los de @Christian? No se entiende cual es la conversación aquí, obviamente no parece haber nada incorrecto sin las aclaraciones del AP.

Comment: Los puntos en python no representan a los decimales? Ejemplo en ingresos corrientes en la variable iap tengo 2019 MILLONES, y en la salida de python tengo 2.019.

Comment: @FacundoCostadeArguibel No tienes 2.019, tienes 2.019e+09. Es decir: 2,019 multiplicado por 10 elevado a 9. Justo el número que se ha leído en Excel.